# React & Express: app.use() routes not working with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io, routes

React Beginner Here. I'm trying to connect an existing react project and socket.io but now I can't access the routes with app.use(). I can see the console logs of the connections and disconnections but when I login with '/login', It doesn't run. Front end runs at 3000, Server at 9000

Edit: It does run because I receive a token which is sent at the end of it. However I get a status 404 Cannot POST /login.

**Socket.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const http = require('http')
const cors = require('cors')
const server = http.createServer(router)

router.use(cors())
const {Server} = require("socket.io")
const io =  new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    }
})
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected')
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected', socket.id)
    })
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg)
        io.emit('chat message', msg)
    })
})


module.exports = {server}
```

**Server.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const {server} = require('./socket/socket')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:9000', 'http://localhost:3001'],
    credentials: true,
}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))


const login = require('./routes/login')
const signup = require('./routes/verify/signup')
const home = require('./routes/home')
const checkRefreshToken = require('./routes/_checkRT')
const logout = require('./routes/_logout')[![enter image description here][1]][1]
const verify = require('./routes/verify/_verify')

app.use('/login', login)
app.use('/signup', signup)
app.use('/', home)
app.use('/check_refresh_token', checkRefreshToken)
app.use('/logout', logout)
app.use('/verification', verify)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000 
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

**front end messages.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/navbar'

import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000/')

const Messages = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Messages
```

**Login.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const cors = require('cors')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
})

// middleware
router.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:9000', 'http://localhost:3001'],
    credentials: true,
}))
router.use(express.json())
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

/**
 * Flow of the code:
 * 1. Check if email exists in the database
 * 2. If it does, check if the password matches
 * 3. If it does, generate an access token
 * 4. Then generate a refresh token
 * 5. Then send the access token and refresh token to the client
 */


router.post('/',  (req, res) => 
{

    // Even these doesn't run
    
    // console.log("HERE"); 
    // res.send("HELLO") 

    const { email, password } = req.body
    function getInput() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let sql = `
            SELECT * FROM account_table
            LEFT JOIN section_table
            ON account_table.account_section_id  = section_table.section_id
            WHERE account_email = ?
        ;`
            connection.query(sql, [email], (err, results) => {
                if (err) return reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
                else if (results.length === 0) return reject({status: 401, message: 'Invalid email or password'})
                return resolve(results)
            })
        })
    }
    function checkPassword(input) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.compare(password, input[0].account_password, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
                else if (!result) return reject({status: 401, message: 'Invalid email or password'})
                return resolve(input)
            })
        })
    }
    function generateAccess(result) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const userAccessToken = { 
                user_id: result[0].account_id,
                user_section_id: result[0].account_section_id
            }

            jwt.sign(userAccessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '15m'}, (err, token) => {
                if (err) return reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
                return resolve(token)
            })
        })
    }
    function generateRefresh(result) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const userAccessToken = { 
                user_id: result[0].account_id,
                user_section_id: result[0].account_section_id
            }

            jwt.sign({userAccessToken}, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, token) => {
                if (err) return reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
                return resolve(token)
            })
        })
    }
    function insertSend(access, refresh, result) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const userInfo = {
                user_f_name: result[0].account_first_name,
                user_l_name: result[0].account_last_name,
                section_grade: result[0].section_grade,
                section_strand: result[0].section_strand,
                section_name: result[0].section_name,
            }
            
            let expiryDate = new Date(Date.now())
            expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 7) // 7 days
            let sql = `INSERT INTO refresh_token_table (token_content, token_owner_id, token_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

            connection.query(sql, [refresh, result[0].account_id, expiryDate], (err, results) => {
                if (err) return reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
                return resolve(
                    res.cookie("hello_world_cookie69", refresh, {
                        origin: "http://localhost:9000",
                        expires: expiryDate,
                        httpOnly: true,
                        secure: true,
                        sameSite: "strict",
                    }).json({userInfo, access})
                )
            })
        })
    }

    try {
        let vEmail = await getInput() 
        let vData = await checkPassword(vEmail) 
        let accessToken = await generateAccess(vData) 
        let refreshToken = await generateRefresh(vData)
        let send = await insertSend(accessToken, refreshToken, vData)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

[image: Screenshot of the response I Get]

Comment: *I get a status 404 Cannot POST /login*: For that issue, please show the code for the `./routes/login` file.  And, also show the client-side code that triggers the login post.  Are you sure your doing the login post on port 9000?  Have you checked the browser dev console for errors when you post?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey dude. I've updated the question

Comment: In login.js, why are you operating on `app`?  And, where is the code that gets or creates that `app` object?  Shouldn't you be using a router that you export?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh I just left it out. I'll add it it in the question. And for the router, I actually don't know about that

Comment: Your login.js should be using a [router](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router) as in `const router = express.Router()`, not another `app`.  So replace that app with a router everywhere in that file and export the router.  You should have one `app` and can then hook up as many routers as you want to it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey again dude. I've modified it but it still doesn't work. I'm not receiving a 404 anymore but there's no response from the server. I've updated the question and attached an image

Comment: @jfriend00 Update: I just decided to move the socket.js to server.js. It worked but the main server file will be dumped by io events

Comment: I don't understand what state its in now and what your remaining questions is.  Have you done basic debugging and followed the execution through your login route handler to see exactly what it does either in the debugger or with `console.log()` statements?  Have you seen what response you get back to the client?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey dude. Sorry for the late reply. I figured it out and it's all good